# Robolectric 3: Shadow custom class

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin

i'm using Robolectric 3 and i'm trying to shadow a custom class like so:

```
public class Yakir {

    public int foo() {
        return 1;
    }


}

@Implements(Yakir.class)
public class TestYakir {

    @Implementation
    public int foo() {
        return 2;
    }


}
```

And I've read on other answers and posts that Robolectric shadows SDK classes and for custom classes I need to do something special Like so:

public class RoboServiceRunner extends RobolectricGradleTestRunner {

```
public RoboServiceRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
    super(klass);
}


@Override
public Config getConfig(Method method) {
    Config config = super.getConfig(method);
    config.shadows();
    return config;
}


@Override
protected ShadowMap createShadowMap(){
    ShadowMap shadowMap = super.createShadowMap();
    shadowMap = shadowMap.newBuilder().addShadowClass(ServiceTest.TestYakir.class).build();
    return shadowMap;
}


}
```

So what you see here is code to add the new class to the shadowMap.
I'm also aware if the [Shadows](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/3.0/org/robolectric/shadows/package-summary.html) class but I cant find what to do with it.

So the output for this test :

```
@RunWith(RoboServiceRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, shadows =   {ServiceTest.TestYakir.class})

 public class ServiceTest {

@Test
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, shadows = {ServiceTest.TestYakir.class})
public void testService() {

    assertEquals(2, new Yakir().foo());

}
```

is:

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 
>   Expected :2
>   Actual   :1

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after more digging around the web I found a simple solution that worked for me.

All you need to do is to override a method in the class that extends

> RobolectricGradleTestRunner

the method is:

```
@Override
public InstrumentationConfiguration createClassLoaderConfig() {
    InstrumentationConfiguration.Builder builder = InstrumentationConfiguration.newBuilder();
    builder.addInstrumentedClass(YourCustomShadowClass.class.getName());
    return builder.build();    }
```

And that's it! Test passed with flying colors :)